# Inheritance class design with "irrelevant" methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, composite, virtual-functions

Say I have the following abstract base class:

```
class DLAContainer {
public:
    DLAContainer() { std::random_device rd; mt_eng = std::mt19937(rd()); }
    virtual void generate(std::size_t _n) = 0;
protected:
    std::mt19937 mt_eng;

    virtual void spawn_particle(int& _x, int& _y,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>& _dist) = 0;
    virtual void spawn_particle(int& _x, int& _y, int& _z,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>& _dist) = 0;

    // ... among other methods to be overridden...
};
```

and two classes which inherit from `DLAContainer`:

```
class DLA_2d : public DLAContainer {
public:
    DLA_2d() : DLAContainer() { // initialise stuff }
    void generate(std::size_t _n) { // do stuff }
private:;
    std::queue<std::pair<int,int>> batch_queue;
    // ...

    void spawn_particle(int& _x, int& _y, 
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>& _dist) { // do stuff }
    void spawn_particle(int& _x, int& _y, int& _z,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>& _dist) { // do nothing }

    //...
};
```

and

```
class DLA_3d : public DLAContainer {
public:
    DLA_3d() : DLAContainer() { // initialise stuff }
    void generate(std::size_t _n) { // do stuff }
private:;
    std::queue<std::tuple<int,int,int>> batch_queue;
    // ...

    void spawn_particle(int& _x, int& _y, 
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>& _dist) { // do nothing }
    void spawn_particle(int& _x, int& _y, int& _z,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<>& _dist) { // do stuff }

    //...
};
```

As you can see, there are two overloads of `spawn_particle` - one for a 2D lattice and the other for 3D, however both are pure `virtual` functions and so must be overridden/implemented in both `DLA_2d` and `DLA_3d` sub-classes where the 3D method will do nothing in `DLA_2d` and vice-versa for `DLA_3d`.

Of course, this works and everything functions normally but I can't help but feel that the design is a bit clumsy when having to implement irrelevant methods in each class.

Is there a better design pattern for this such as implementing separate interfaces (i.e. `ISpawnParticle_2d` and `ISpawnParticle_3d`) for the two derived classes? Or would composition rather than inheritance be favoured in such a scenario?

**Edit:** I should add that `DLAContainer` has several other methods (and fields). Some of these methods are defined (such that they can be used by both `DLA_2d` and `DLA_3d`) and others are pure-virtual similar to `spawn_particle` - this is why I have `DLAContainer` as an abstract base class in this case.

Comment: If there's nothing else in `DLAContainer`, I see little need to make it an abtract class. Just have it store the random number generator, subclass it, implement the appropriate `spawn_article()` in each subclass, and call it a day. If you really need an abtract class, throwing an exception is better than doing nothing, in the not-implemented function. An alternative is to define the default implementations of the virtual functions in the base class (hence it's not an abstract class any more), by throwing an exception.

Comment: I omitted a fair amount of the actual code from `DLAContainer` - there's more to it and ideally it needs to be an abstract class. Interesting idea with the exception throwing definitions in the base class, that might be nicer - plus `DLAContainer` would still be abstract in this case as `generate(std::size_t)` would remain pure-virtual as signature is equivalent for `DLA_2d` and `DLA_3d`.

Comment: You need to know the type of the object before calling either of your `spawn_particle()` functions so there is no benefit to their being in the base class at all. You may as well be declared each one in their relevant subclass.

Comment: @Galik Hmmm, that's a very good point actually

Comment: @Galik What you say appears likely, but is not supported by evidence. The base class defines an interface and perhaps there is a use case for this full interface, who knows?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Throwing an exception should really only be a last resort. If the classes are used incorrectly, you want catch this at compile-time rather than run-time. So throwing is kind of admitting defeat: _Unable to design an interface that's easy to use and difficult to break._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it is clumsy.
And it's the result of a common mistake in OO design: *Using inheritance merely to avoid code duplication when the subtype cannot be said to be **IS A** parent type.*

Currently you're able to call:

```
DLA_3d d3;
d3.spawn_particle(...) //The 2D version
//and
DLA_2d d2;
d2.spawn_particle(...) //The 3D version
```

With seemingly no "ill effects" by ignoring the call and doing nothing. The problem is that code calling `spawn_particle` needs to be aware that:

- Calling the method might do nothing.
- Or pre-check the type to know which method to call.

Both of these impose unnecessary extra knowledge/work on the caller. And effectively make it more error-prone to use.

**PS**: Note that throwing an error at runtime doesn't really fix the design. Because callers are now left with: "*Calling the method might throw* OR pre-check the type..."

---

There are a number of ways you can improve your design. But ultimately you know what you're trying to achieve and will have to make that decision yourself.
Here are a few ideas:

- First a foremost consider the following design principle: *Favour composition over inheritance*.

  - You don't need to inherit to reuse code: you can contain/reference an instance of another object, and offload work by calling the contained/referenced object.
  - You mentioned that `DLAContainer` has a number of other fields and methods. How many of those can be moved to a different or multiple classes?
- Does it really make sense for the container to be spawning particles? The container's responsibility should be to hold things. Are you following the *Single Responsibility Principle*? (I doubt it.)
- Consider moving each `spawn_particle` method to the appropriate subclass. (Though I suspect this will leave you with very much the same kind of problems.)
- Develop an abstraction for "particle". Then both "particle spawners" can have the same signature, but spawn different concrete instances of "particle" I.e. a 2D particle or a 3D particle.

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem here is the inconsistency of the interface declared by the abstract base class. Is this supposed to be a 2D or 3D interface? The way you declared it, it's both, but the derived classes are either and hence do not fully implement the interface: this causes all your problems.

Think about how are you going to use the base class, perhaps you can make it a template over the number of dimensions? If there are more `virtual` methods inpendent of the dimensionality, they could be in a base, e.g.

```
struct DLAContainerBase
{
  /* some basic virtual interface */
};

template<int Dims>
struct DLAContainer : DLAContainerBase
{
  virtual void spawn_particle(std::array<int,Dims>&,
                              std::uniform_real_distribution<>&) = 0;
};
```

But w/o knowing how the base is going to be used, I cannot really give you reliable advise. Btw, you can also provide an implementation for a pure virtual method (e.g. one that throws).